# django cache.clear() ending session (logout)

Tags: python, django, django-sessions, django-cache

I'm using memcached in Django to cache the entire site.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache

I've added some code in a post-save signal handler method to clear the cache when certain objects are created or updated in the model.

```
from proximity.models import Advert

# Cache
from django.core.cache import cache

@receiver(post_save, sender=Advert)
def save_advert(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Clear cache
    cache.clear()
```

Unfortunately now after creating a new object, the user is logged out.

I think that the reason can be that I'm caching sessions.

```
# Cache config
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 31449600 #(approximately 1 year, in seconds)
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = COREAPP
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache",
        "LOCATION": "127.0.0.1:11211",
    }
}
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

Should I use per-view cache maybe?

Comment: It's unclear what "cache entire site" is.

Comment: I've cached the entire site as described in django docs,  chaching the requests at the middleware level, using  'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware' and 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware'. I've added a link to the docs.

Comment: clearing the cache will clear out any saved sessions. You should either use a different session backend or change the way that you cache. Do you really need to cache every single request?

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington, what I really need is to cache some DRF API calls, but i couldn't find an easy way to do that, because I cant use the decorator '@cache_page'. Then I cached the entire site and then excluded some pages.  Which other sessions engine can I use?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash

update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
```

pass request and user in above method when you clearing a cache. but according to your way. you are clearing cache in signal that don't have request. So if you are updating Advert model from admin then. override admin `save_model()` method to save and here you can get user and request, So call above `update_session_auth_hash` after clear cache. It will not logged out user. If you updating data from own view then use same to call method that continue user as logged in.

**Edit**

```
def form_valid(self, form)
    user = self.request.user
    form.save()  # When you save then signal will call that clear your cache
    update_session_auth_hash(self.request, user)
```

Comment: The object is being created from a CreateVIew. I've overridden the method form_valid and called update_session_auth_hash(request, user) before saving the object and clearing cache, but user still being logged out.